Nuxt interfering with Google sign-in on external API
I have an ASP.NET Core api which does authentication (username and password, google, injects jwt into cookies). I want to use that server for authentication in my nuxt app.
Right now, I'm trying to get google authentication to work. And if I just type the url localhost:7132/api/auth/google, which challenges the google scheme on the backend I get redirected to google and the cookie gets set finally. Client authenticated! Done!
However, if I try localhost:3000/api/auth/google (the nuxt host, which proxies api requests), I get the google sign-in page, but with a bunch of errors in the console.


And can't move past the first google page (email entry).
The url also looks like localhost:3000/v3/signin.... which isn't great.
It seems google is being loaded inside nuxt which manipulates it's links and doesn't let it work.
What should I do?

I believe you are using relative URL /api/auth/google in link tag, try with domain name like this - localhost:7132/api/auth/google

That logs in straight away without showing the login page (trying to log out rn). But why doesn't the proxy do it? I don't want to hard code the api address everywhere.
